# How to use swing timer?

Tags: java, swing, timer, actionlistener

I'm trying to write a program that draws a new square every second. This is my code for my JPannel class. I have two other classes but I beleive they are irrelivant to my question. One has the main method where it creates an object of the other class that contains the JFrame. I just cant figure out how to get the timer to work and how it works.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
public class Drawing extends JPanel  implements ActionListener{
    Drawing(){
        super();
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        startTimer();        
    }

    public void startTimer() {
           Timer timer = new Timer(1000, this);
           timer.start();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
         int width = getWidth();             
         int height = getHeight();         

         super.paintComponent(g);  
         g.setColor(Color.BLUE);

         for(int x = 0; x < 999; x ++) {
         for(int y = 0; y < 999; y ++) {

                 g.drawRect(0,0, x, y);


         }
         }

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
           repaint();
    }

}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). An MCVE needs a `main(String[])` to run it.  2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Comment: Get rid of the for loops in your paintComponent method. Note that painting methods should not change object state. Instead the timer's actionPerformed method gets repeatedly called -- advance your counter or x/y variables there, and then call `repaint()`.

Comment: The way you're defined the timer, it fires every second and then calls repaint() in your actionPerformed method. You seem to be on the right track. Have your actionPerformed draw the new sqaure, and don't forget to call startTimer() somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the for loops in your paintComponent method. Note that painting methods should not change object state. Instead the timer's actionPerformed method gets repeatedly called -- advance your counter or x/y variables there, and then call `repaint()`.

e.g.,

```
private int x;
private int y;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
     super.paintComponent(g);  
     g.setColor(Color.BLUE);


     // RECT_WIDTH etc are constants
     g.drawRect(x, y, RECT_WIDTH, RECT_HEIGHT);
}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
    int width = getWidth();             
    int height = getHeight();

    // code here to change the object's state -- here to change
    // location of the rectangle
    x++;
    y++;

    // TODO: check that x and y are not beyond bounds and if so,
    // then re-position them

    repaint();
}
```

Comment: @AshwinGupta: you're welcome. The key is to change state that needs to be incrementally changed within the Timer ActionListener's actionPerformed method. Note that for real non-toy programs, you'll not want your GUI classes implement listener interfaces as that's giving a class too much responsibility.